# Want to fetch xml Values from string parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, string

I have following xml in string variable-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<person>
  <first-name>RaJeEv(๏๏)</first-name>
  <last-name>Diboliya</last-name>
  <headline>Software Engineer at FASTTRACK INDIA.</headline>
  <site-standard-profile-request>
    <url>http://www.linkedin.com/profile?viewProfile=&amp;url>
  </site-standard-profile-request>
</person>
```

Now I want to get first and last name from this string. How can I do this?

Comment: What have you already tried, what approaches have you considered?

Comment: I have not tried anything, because I dont have any idea about this.

Comment: You can also create a strongly typed class and deserialize the data into it.

Comment: @Middas: How can I deserialize the class?

Comment: Create a class that matches the data then use the XmlSerializer to deserialize your XML data into that class.  Here is an example site: http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/csharp/xmlserializer-example.htm

Comment: Here is one example, if you make it class - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947561/send-xml-string-as-response/2948028#2948028

Comment: read it into an `XmlDocument` or `XDocument` and use XPath to extract what you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for example

```
public class Program {
    public static void Main(String[] args) {
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""     standalone=""yes""?>
<person>
  <first-name>RaJeEv(๏๏)</first-name>
  <last-name>Diboliya</last-name>
  <headline>Software Engineer at FASTTRACK INDIA.</headline>
  <site-standard-profile-request>
    <url>http://www.linkedin.com/profile?viewProfile</url>
  </site-standard-profile-request>
</person>");

        XElement xe = xdoc.Elements("person").First();

        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", xe.Element("first-name").Value, xe.Element("last-name").Value);
    }         
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would deserialize this -

Create a concrete domain class `Person`

```
[Serializable()]
public class Person
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("first-name")]
    public string FirstName{ get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("last-name")]
    public string LastName{ get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("headline")]
    public string Headline{ get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("site-standard-profile-request")]
    public string ProfileRequest{ get; set; }
}
```

The use XmlSerializer to convert it to Person type

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person));
var person = serializer.Deserialize(xml) as Person;
```

The properties can then be accessed like

```
var firstName = person.FirstName;
var lastName = person.LastName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Right on the MSDN

[Parse XML with XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056(v=vs.95).aspx)

but if you have this struct in a class strong type you can also see this answer on how you convert it to xml and back: 
[Send XML String as Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947561/send-xml-string-as-response/2948028#2948028)

Answer (score 0):

```
var person = XElement.Parse(yourString).Element("person");
string firstName = person.Element("first-name").Value;
string lastName = person.Element("last-name").Value;
```

Comment: Could you add some comments to your code? It will be more meaningful for others. Check this [metaSO question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question) and [Jon Skeet: Coding Blog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully.aspx) on how to give a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for..

```
        XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlNodeList xmlnode;
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(xmlFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        xmldoc.Load(fs);

        xmlnode = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("first-name");
        string firstname= string.Empty;
        if(xmlnode!=null)
            strOption = Regex.Replace(xmlnode[0].InnerText, @"\t|\n|\r| ", "");

        xmlnode = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("last-name");
        string lastname= string.Empty;
        if(xmlnode!=null)
            strOption = Regex.Replace(xmlnode[0].InnerText, @"\t|\n|\r| ", "");
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: no offense meant because ok, this works, but there's no added value in telling someone, who's trying to understand how to extract values from an XML string, to use Regex. That's over-complicating things. C# has methods built in to deal with XPath and to get to the `InnerText` of an XML node.

Comment: @WimOmbelets : That's not over-complicating, that's necessary, because if your xml has values like tab/new-line for viewing-purpose, then you gonna have to replace each tab,new-line,trim to get the absolute string. And `Regex` is way more faster to do this that individual `string.Replace` and `Trim`.

Comment: if XML has 'presentation' characters in its values, you track down who did that and [insert very bad juju here]